# Validate Endpoint - Custom Journey Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

Good afternoon all,

We're currently creating a custom journey activity within Marketing Cloud and we aren't really clear regarding the validate and test endpoints.

We configured these on config of the custom activity, tested locally, but when we trigger the validate within the Journey Planner, it doesn't call the endpoint at all.

[image]

We noticed though, that Validate and test endpoints are triggered only when the Journey is activated/ executed.

With that said, seems the validate is not being triggered for Custom Activities, only the journey is activated.

Is that default from Marketing Cloud?

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: If you click on activate the activity is validated correctly and you dont get errors?

Comment: If I activate the journey I don't get any errors. So, to be clear, the Journey planner offers the Validate option that doesn't seem to validate custom activities. However, when activating the journey it does call the validate endpoint for custom activities. Quite controversial, why the Validate doesn't call validate points for custom activities - not sure if we're missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The validate functionality is only to check all your configurations are valid like Email templates, Logical Conditions, Journey goal. So basically will go and try to find if You have missed any **required** configuration enough to run the Journey.

In a case of a custom activity, that is not part of this validation as You can find in the documentation. That need to be validated outside this *Validate* check.

Also recall there's an [idea exchange site](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) specially for this case when You want to request new functionality into the platform. Hope this solves your question.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_validate_your_journey.htm&type=5)